# Can't find element by xpath selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to find maximum number of pages (which is 20)
But it cant find the element. [Website link](https://etherscan.io/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52#balances)

---

[image]

Code:

```py
from functools import total_ordering
from pandas.core.base import DataError
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import string
from csv import reader
import code
import pandas

from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://etherscan.io/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52#balances")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
num = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='d-inline-block']//*[@class=page-link text-nowrap]")))
print(num)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is in **iframe**, so please switch to it before interaction.

The below code I have tried in **firefox** :

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://etherscan.io/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52#balances")
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "tokeholdersiframe")))
num = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//span[contains(@class,'page-link text-nowrap')]/strong)[2]")))
print(num.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

In case you want to print 1 of 20, please use below xpath

```
//span[contains(@class,'page-link text-nowrap')]
```

Comment: I am trying it but my code goes into time out. any idea?

Comment: No that shouldn't happen. Are you using Firefox ? Make sure to copy my code carefully. It won't throw any error.

Comment: yes, i'll check again.

Comment: In my answer I have maximized the screen also, please make sure to do the exact same steps which are mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

Need to switch to `iframe` and then try to find the `pagination` Elements.

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"tokeholdersiframe")))

num = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='d-inline-block']//strong[2]"))).text
print(num)

# print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='d-inline-block']//strong[2]").text)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

```
20
```

Comment: any idea why it may go into timeout?

Comment: @HamzaAhmed - Are you trying to click on `Page 1 of 20`. If yes, that is not a clickable Element.

Comment: And the xpath `//div[@class='d-inline-block']//*[@class=page-link text-nowrap]` is not highlighting the required Element. Go through the - [https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/)

Comment: I am trying to get the value that is 20.

Comment: The wait condition is `element_to_be_clickable` hence the issue. Change it to `presence_of_element_located`

Comment: @HamzaAhmed - Have reupdated the answer. Try with `presence_of_element_located` condition not `element_to_be_clickable`

Comment: Also you can refer - [https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)